# how to draw multiple plots in coreplot

Tags: core-plot

I need to draw multiple plots in the same graph at different times. Please look at the image below:

[image: Need graph like this]

Except that the number of plots would change dynamically. Sometimes I would only require only blue and orange datasets some times all four and some times only 3. I am able to manage for one bar plot like this.

```
CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
plot.dataSource = self;
plot.identifier = @"mainplot";
plot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
plot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
[self.graph addPlot:plot];
```

In my case I can put them in a for loop and do `[self.graph addplot:plot]` in each iteration. But how do I manage the datasource. How do I manage the code below, if the number of datasets changes dynamically.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"mainplot"] )
    {
        NSValue *value = [self.graphData objectAtIndex:index];
        CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];

        // FieldEnum determines if we return an X or Y value.
        if ( fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX )
        {
            return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.x];
        }
        else    // Y-Axis
        {
            return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.y];
        }
    }

    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it before and it worked! You can use an `NSArray` for plots, and create some plot data and add them as objects into a `NSDictionary`. for more detail you can see this sample:

```
NSDictionary *firstLineDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"firstLine", PLOT_IDENTIFIER, firstLineData, PLOT_DATA, nil];
NSDictionary *secondLineDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"secondLine", PLOT_IDENTIFIER, secondLineData, PLOT_DATA, nil];
NSArray *arrayData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstLineDic, secondLineDic, nil];
scatterPlot = [[ScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:plotView data:arrayData];
[scatterPlot initialisePlot];
```

Now in `ScatterPlot` class write these functions:

```
-(id)initWithHostingView:(CPTGraphHostingView *)_hostingView data:(NSArray *)_data{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self != nil ) {
        self.hostingView = _hostingView;
        data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_data];
        self.graph = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initialisePlot
{

...

    for (NSDictionary *dic in data) {
        CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
        plot.dataSource = self;
        plot.identifier = [dic objectForKey:PLOT_IDENTIFIER];
        plot.dataLineStyle = [lineStyles objectAtIndex:[dic objectForKey:PLOT_COLOR]];
        plot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
        [self.graph addPlot:plot];
    }

...

}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot 
{
    for (NSDictionary *dic in data) {
        NSString *identity = [dic objectForKey:PLOT_IDENTIFIER];
        if([plot.identifier isEqual:identity]){
            NSArray *arr = [dic objectForKey:PLOT_DATA];
            return [arr count];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if i dont know how many lines i am going to have? any suggestions?

Comment: @BorisGafurov Use `NSMutableArray`instead of `NSArray` for `PLOT_DATA`!

Answer (score 0):

Check for different plot identifiers, and return other data then.

Comment: Hi MrMage,Thanks for your quichk response , can you tell me how would i  allocate dynamic identifiers and the tougher question is how to compare them in the if loop if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"mainplot"] ). in the above sample @"mainplot" is hard coded. how would i change this to be dynamic.

Comment: I'm sure that you are able to figure that out yourself if you think about it a bit.

Comment: i am giving my best guess.

      CPTPlot *tempPlot = [self.graph objectatindex:indexpath.row];           if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:tempPlot.identifier] ) // i am sure self.graph will not take objectatindex method. i want to know what method it can take?

Comment: The identifier is declared as `id<NSCopying, NSCoding, NSObject>`. It doesn't have to be a string. A simple way would be to encode the index as an `NSNumber` and use that as the identifier.